# Classic ASP to convert a string of win1251 codes into the original cyrillic

Tags: asp-classic, character-encoding

I have a problem in a Russian site that is written in Classic ASP.

I had massive encoding issues with the site and the database which I managed to fix via much googling using the following code at the top of the pages:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript  CODEPAGE="65001"%>
```

However some data in the SQL db refuses to be stored as NVARCHAR even if I insert using:`N'[cyrillic_goes_here]'`.

To get around this I am currently storing the data as win1251 encoded so I have a stream that consists of `&#1053;` as an example.

*Is there a way in classic ASP to convert a string of these codes into the original cyrillic **before** they get displayed? (2 reasons: SEO friendliness and the main issue is with a form and form names which don't work when processing the form*).

Comment: `However some data in the SQL db refuses to be stored as NVARCHAR ` , could you please explain that ?

Comment: Instead of the correct Cyrillic being stored I get strings of question marks even if I use `N'[cyrillic]'` which should keep the cyrillic in it's correct form in the database - for some reason this appears to work differently across the database (it's someone else's system I'm trying to fix)

Comment: the insertion page is classic asp ?

Comment: yes, it is part of a form builder that creates fields and then inserts them into the database